# Could a 3+1 space be embedded in a 4+1 space and retain its 3+1 characteristics?

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions, branes

I'm confused because I can conceptualize this embedding scenario in two seemingly incompatible ways.

Which of the following scenarios are possible?:

1) 4+1 space automatically enforces 4 dimensions of spacial freedom on anything and everything embedded in it. This would lead to popular 3D-to-4D fates, such as unstable orbits and unraveling humans. In other words, incompatible with life as we know it.

and/or

2) A dimensional analogy type view wherein 4+1 space may contain objects that are comprised of 3+1 "planes" that are stacked along the fourth direction. The individual 3+1 planes retain their constraint to 3 spacial dimensions, and hence life as we know it would remain possible on a plane (with movement between planes prohibited).

I hope my question makes some sense.

Comment: See [Brane Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) but note that this is all highly speculative. In the absense of any experimental support we can't answer your question except to say that option 2 is realised in some theories.

Comment: Would it be safe to say, more generally, that an n-dimensional space does not necessarily enforce all of its degrees of freedom on embedded objects, e.g. the surface of a balloon having only 2 dimensions of freedom? Or is that an illusion that disregards the molecular texture of the balloon surface?

Comment: The dimensionality of the space doesn't enforce anything. If something is restricted to a submanifold there must be some other effect at work. For example in brane cosmology it's because open string ends are confined to a brane. In the real (3+1D) world I don't know of anything that is truely 2+1D. All the 2D systems I know of are only 2D above some length scale.

Comment: You can't embed in 4 spatial dimensions. If I remember correctly, it would take at least 6 dimensions to even embed a flat Minkowski space.